# Selecting Operational Amplifiers

Tags: operational-amplifier

Are there any tools for selecting commercial Operational Amplifiers by filtering the results with some characteristic (not only bias current and input offset voltage bat also for example the input offset voltage temperature drift)? In my experience the best I have found is Mouser website.
Thanks all.

Comment: Any good distributor or manufacturer will have some kind of filtering, the majority of the battle is knowing what parameters matter for a specific application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the Linear technology search engines are pretty good. Here's one example which shows bias current, offset voltage and offset voltage drift: -

[image]

I'm pretty sure the analogue devices site will do similar but a little more long-winded: -

[image]

What about TI? Possibly but in my 1 minute search I could only find this: -

[image]